# Swift 4 AVFoundation - Recording multiple audio sources simultaneously

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation, audio-recording

I am currently trying to monitor the audio input of each internal microphones  of an iPhone simultaneously.

In the undermentioned code, I am picking the microphone I would like to monitor/meter (bottom, front or back microphone) with this line of code:

```
try recordingSession.setInputDataSource(recordingSession.inputDataSources?[2])
```

Unfortunately it seems like I can only set one input data source for my audio session.

Maybe is there a way to set an input data source per recording channel ?

I have alose tried to explore other solutions such as AVAudioEngine but as there is not a lot of Swift ressources about this topic, it makes it quite complicated to me to analyse which way to go.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

        class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioRecorderDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

            @IBOutlet var recordButton: UIButton!
            var recordingSession: AVAudioSession!
            var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
            var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder!

            var timer: Timer!

            override func viewDidLoad() {
                recordingSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

                do {
                    try recordingSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute)
                    //try recordingSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement)
                    try recordingSession.setActive(true)


                    try recordingSession.setInputDataSource(recordingSession.inputDataSources?[2])
                    try recordingSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.speaker)
                    recordingSession.requestRecordPermission() { [unowned self] allowed in
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            if allowed {

                            } else {
                                // failed to record!
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("NOT ALLOWED")
                    // failed to record!
                }

            }

            @objc func updateMeters(){
                audioRecorder.updateMeters()


                print("CHANNEL 0 PEAK : \(audioRecorder.peakPower(forChannel: 0))")
                print("CHANNEL 1 PEAK : \(audioRecorder.peakPower(forChannel: 1))")
                print(audioRecorder.averagePower(forChannel: 0))
                print(audioRecorder.currentTime)
            }


            func startRecording() {
                let audioFilename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("recording.m4a")

                let settings = [
                    AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                    AVSampleRateKey: 12000,
                    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
                    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
                ]

                do {

                    audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename, settings: settings)
                    audioRecorder.delegate = self
                    audioRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
                    audioRecorder.record()

                    recordButton.setTitle("Tap to Stop", for: .normal)

                    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateMeters), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
                } catch {
                    finishRecording(success: false)
                }
            }

            func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
                let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
                let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
                return documentsDirectory
            }

            func finishRecording(success: Bool) {
                timer.invalidate()
                audioRecorder.stop()
                audioRecorder = nil

                if success {
                    recordButton.setTitle("Tap to Re-record", for: .normal)
                } else {
                    recordButton.setTitle("Tap to Record", for: .normal)
                    // recording failed :(
                }
            }

            @IBAction func recordTapped() {
                if audioRecorder == nil {
                    startRecording()
                } else {
                    finishRecording(success: true)
                }
            }

            func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool) {
                if !flag {
                    finishRecording(success: false)
                }
            }

            @IBAction func play(_ sender: UIButton) {
                let fileURL = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("recording.m4a")
                    self.audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: fileURL)
                    self.audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                    self.audioPlayer.delegate = self
                    self.audioPlayer.play()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As mention in this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/64lba1/are_there_any_apps_that_record_stereo_audio_from/) by *smakusdod*:

> The iphone has 3 mics... used like an array depending on which camera
>   is active, or if you are in speakerphone mode etc. if apple wanted to,
>   they could purpose these mics for stereo recording. E.g., using the
>   bottom mic for right channel, and top mic for left channel. Currently
>   they do not allow this, and instead only expose a mono channel.

Because apple provides only a mono channel implies that it is impossible for iOS developers to simultaneously access to each of those internal microphone for us.

If you feel like it should be possible, Apple gives you the opportunity to let them know:
https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html

Comment: Maybe the hardware doesn't support it.